How to update PrimeVue InputNumber ref immediately?
In vanilla Vue and PrimeVue, when using InputText, changes are applied immediately, updating the value of the linked ref as you type. However, with InputNumber, the changes don’t apply immediately; they only update when you press Enter. Why does this happen, and how can you make it apply right away?
InputText sample
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext'
</script>

<template>
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <InputText v-model="msg" />
</template>

InputNumber sample
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref(42)
import InputNumber from 'primevue/inputnumber'
</script>

<template>
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <InputNumber v-model="msg" />
</template>


That's the way it works. You can expand the component and change the respective methods, https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/4.1.1/packages/primevue/src/inputnumber/InputNumber.vue#L416-L419 . But I assume the current behaviour is for a reason, this would prevent a user from inputting certain values

It looks like this is a feature in this component, I read the component API and there's nothing to disable this behavior, but if you want to get the immediate updates try to use the @input event with :model-value :
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

const msg = ref(5);
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <h1>Playground</h1>
    <InputNumber :model-value="msg" @input="(e) => (msg = e.value)" />
    <p>{{ msg }}</p>
  </main>
</template>


The value is updated only when the InputNumber loses focus. So, here is a function that removes focus from the InputNumber to update the value and then immediately focuses it again.
<template>
  <h1>Value: {{ modelValue }}</h1>
  <div>
    <InputNumber v-model="modelValue" @input="refocus" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

const modelValue = ref<number>(0);

function refocus($event: InputNumberInputEvent) {
  const target = $event.originalEvent.target as HTMLElement;
  target.blur();
  target.focus();
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>

